# uiautomatorviewer no longer shows resource-id

Tags: android-sdk-tools, android-uiautomator

I use uiautomatorviewer to quickly get resource-ids to create acceptance tests, but in the past few weeks, I noticed that the field is no longer present. I'm unsure whether it's something on my end, or the tool that changed.

Previously, I could view the resource-id of an element:
[image]

Now, the resource-id field is no longer present (the element selected *does* have an id):
[image]

I just updated to Android SDK Tools 22.3, but this was happening before the update. Unfortunately, I didn't take note of what version this started happening in. :/

Comment: Just reference by content description. The Resource id still shows on my viewer, but I never use it.

Comment: @Binghammer While that would be ideal (since content-descs make the app more accessible), as you can see above, some elements don't have them. The elements do have resource-ids, though, which is why I want to find them using uiautomatorviewer and not have to dig through /res/layout/.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably the problem is on Android Version? 
I'm using uiautomatorviewer connecting with a Galaxy Samsung S4 (GT-I9505) with Android 4.3 and I can see resource-id from the viewer but I can't using a Samsung Galaxy Note II (GT-N7100) with android 4.1.2.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I guess it's not supported <= API level 17 (4.2), and all my emulators are using 4.2. I just made a Galaxy S4 with 4.3 and it shows the resource-id, but it doesn't show it with a Galaxy S4 with 4.2. Thanks! Perhaps I flubbed up which emulator had which version, since I had thought I had tried with 4.3 before...

Answer (score 2):

Visibility of the resource id is dependent on Adnroid version. Its supported from Android version 4.3 or later/ from API level 18. One of our dev confirmed too.

Another reference: [real device Vs emulator : uiautomator does not show resource-id for the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21399503/real-device-vs-emulator-uiautomator-does-not-show-resource-id-for-the-app)

thanks,
Ravikanth

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to view the resource id based on the device you are using. Some devices don't allow developers to show the resource id using uiauromator viewer. try using nexus devices and you will find the resource ids shown.

Comment: The above screenshots were taken when using uiautomatorviewer on a Nexus 4 AVD (API level 18), which it used to work on. I tried again using it on a Genymotion emulator (Nexus 4, API level 17) and it still doesn't work. I've also tried to use it on various real devices, including Galaxy S4 and Galaxy Note.